# How to use nuget packages in azure devops?

Tags: azure, visual-studio, selenium, azure-devops

Im trying to setup a selenium testproject in azure devops, so i can run it in a pipeline.

I created a project in Visual Studio 2017 and everything works fine. When i try to publish my local code into the azure repository, it doesnt upload my nuget packages and selenium doesnt run without them. How can i solve this? I dont have access to Azure Artifacts btw

Im following these tutorials:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcAMgPywsJA

Answer (score 0):

You need to either manually(via command line)  or automatically (a pipeline) publish your Nuget package to Azure Artifacts. Checkout [Publish a NuGet package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/publish?view=azure-devops).

Once you publish your Nuget package, you won't be able to change its version, or overwrite. Just take in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i solve this? I dont have access to Azure Artifacts btw

As a workaround, you can set up [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) and use it to run the pipeline.

Then set the path to install the package to the path where the local package is located in the `nuget.config` file.

[nuget.config reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file)